# Error creating .war file

Tags: tomcat7

I am testing Tomcat7 showing data from the example table "malaga_plagues". I have done changes but, when I try test it again, I obtain the following error creating .war file.

```
[root@host-192-168-192-78 AMS_Widhoc]# ../../../apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn package
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[root@host-192-168-192-78 AMS_Widhoc]#
```

One month ago this was working fine, but now I have resumed the example and it does not work. I reinstalled Orion CB in mi VM but I didn't change anything in Tomcat.
Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maven 3.3.3 is only compatible with Java 7+, and it seems that you are trying to run it with Java 6. Please check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, it should point to a Java 7 JDK.

Comment: Thank you. It already works. I had installed java version 7 but JAVA_HOME was pointing to previous version.